# Well-Posedness PDE of the Form $\partial_t u = P(\partial_x) u$ for a Polynomial $P$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, continuity, normed-spaces

My question is to determine whether the PDE $\partial_t u = P(\partial_x) u$, with $2\pi$-periodic boundary conditions, for a polynomial $P$, is well-posed; this depends on the polynomial, and my three specific cases are the following:

- $P(y) = y^3$
- $P(y) = y^2$ (heat equation)
- $P(y) = iy^2$ (Schrödinger equation)

Taking Fourier transforms of the original equation, we obtain the general solution
$$ u(t,x) = \sum_{m \in \Bbb Z} e^{tP(im)+imx} \hat u(0,m). $$

I then tried considering two solutions $u$ and $v$, and look at their $L^2$ norm difference,
$$ \| u(t) - v(t) \| _{L^2} = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |u(t,x) - v(t,x)|^2 dx,$$
and then try to manipulate that (using Parseval-Plancherel and orthogonality of complex exponentials) to get a $\le$-inequality with the above on the LHS and $$c \|u(0)-v(0)\| _{L^2}$$ on the RHS, for some constant $c$; unfortunately, I was unable to. Any help would be most appreciated!

Please note: I realise that there's lots on information on the web about well-posedness of PDEs; I hope that this isn't a duplicate, but I can't check every single question that just says "Is this PDE well-posed?" =P

Comment: Since writing this question, I have tried it using the Fourier inversion $$u(t,x) = \int _{\Bbb R} e^{i \xi x} \hat u(t,\xi) dx$$ instead of $$u(t,x) = \sum_{m \in \Bbb Z} \hat u(m) e^{imx}. $$ Using this, I was able to get the required result. <br/> Is someone still able to show me how to do it using the discrete sum, not integral, though? In my lecture notes, it writes the solution in the infinite sum way, then says that it can be used (along with Parseval-Plancherel) to show that the Schrödinger equation is well-posed, so I assume that it can be done *fairly* easily with the discrete sum...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that $\def\norm#1{\left\|#1\right\|}$
\begin{align*}
  \norm{u(t)-v(t)}^2_{L^2} &= 2\pi\norm{\widehat{u(t)} - \widehat{v(t)}}^2_{\ell^2(\def\Z{\mathbb Z}\Z)}\\
       &= 2\pi\sum_{m\in\Z}\def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{e^{tP(im)}\bigl(\hat u(0,m)-\hat v(0,m)\bigr)}^2
\end{align*}
Now note that if $P$ maps the imaginary axis into itself, that is $P[i\mathbb R]\subseteq i\mathbb R$, as do $y^3$ and $iy^2$, but not $y^2$, we have $P(im) = i\alpha(P, m)$, for some real number $\alpha(P, m)$, giving 
\begin{align*}
  \norm{u(t)-v(t)}^2_{L^2} 
       &= 2\pi\sum_{m\in\Z}\abs{e^{tP(im)}\bigl(\hat u(0,m)-\hat v(0,m)\bigr)}^2\\
       &= 2 \pi\sum_{m\in\Z}\abs{e^{ti\alpha(P,m)}}^2\abs{\hat u(0,m)-\hat v(0,m)}^2\\
       &= 2\pi\sum_{m\in\Z}\abs{\hat u(0,m)-\hat v(0,m)}^2\\
       &= \norm{u(0) - v(0)}^2_{L^2}
\end{align*}
If we have the weaker property $P[i\mathbb R] \subseteq \{z \in \mathbb C \mid \Re z \le M\}$ for some $M$, we get along the same line of thought
$$   \norm{u(t)-v(t)}^2_{L^2}  \le e^{tM\cdot 2}   \norm{u(0)-v(0)}^2_{L^2} $$
This works for the heat equation, as $(ix)^2 = -x^2 \le 0$.

---

Addendum:
For $u \in L^2([0,2\pi])$, $u(x) = \sum_{m\in \Z} e^{imx}\hat u(m)$, we have due to the orthogonality of the exponential functions 
\begin{align*}
  \norm{u}_{L^2}^2 &= \norm{\sum_{m\in Z}e^{im\cdot}\hat u(m)}_{L^2}^2\\
    &= \sum_{m,n} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{imx}\hat u(m)e^{-inx}\overline{\hat u(n)}\, dx\\
    &= \sum_n \int_0^{2\pi} e^{0}\hat u(n)\overline{\hat u(n)}\, dx\\
    &= 2\pi \sum_ n \abs{\hat u(n)}^2\\
    &= 2\pi \norm{\hat u}_{\ell^2(\Z)}^2
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's basically what I did to bound the exponential term (in fact, pretty much exactly what I did), but I didn't know about the first norm equivalence. How would you show the equivalence of the norms?

Comment: @SmileySam That's orthogonality, see above.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you. I guess that that way works out pretty similarly to using the integral form of the Fourier inversion, because then you use the orthogonality in the same way. Thanks!