# Well posedness of PDEs of the form $u_{tt} + \left[ P ( \partial_x)\right]^2u=0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series

Let $P$ be a polynomial with real coefficients. I want to find the necessary&sufficient conditions on $P$ in order for the problem 
$$u_{tt} + \left[ P ( \partial_x)\right]^2u=0$$

with

- $u (0,x) = f(x)$
- $ u_t(0,x) = 0$

to be well-posed for every positive period of the data $f$.

I am tempted to decompose the PDE to the form 
$$P_1(\partial_t,\partial_x) \cdot \overline{P_1(\partial_t,\partial_x)}u=0$$ where $P_1(\partial_t,\partial_x) = \partial_t+iP(\partial_x)$ and $\overline{P_1(\partial_t,\partial_x)} =\partial_t - iP(\partial_x) $ is it's complex conjugate. But I don't know how to take it from there...

Comment: [This might be useful](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868859/well-posedness-pde-of-the-form-partial-t-u-p-partial-x-u-for-a-polynomial?rq=1).

Comment: @Mattos I saw it, and tried to apply it to here... I'm still trying without success, can you see how to use it?

Comment: When you say 'well-posed for every positive period of the data $f$,' do you mean that the equation is posed on a periodic domain? (I assume so, since you've tagged the question with [fourier-series])

Comment: @Strants Indeed!